# Advice on making wood hinges

Tags: wood, dowel, hinges

I am making some wood hinges for a table that will have a box in the back and simply open up. I did find a good design for making a wood hinge. The only question that remains: How should I cut the sections out between the hinge "knuckles" (if that is what they are called)?

I was thinking of having them on a sled and running it through the router to do this.

Comment: There are oodles of hinge styles some designs and some might lend to wood. What would you be using these for? Are you just going for a basic door hinge? Have you seen something online that you want to recreate?

Comment: There are many different styles of hinges, and there are some commercially-produced hinge-making jigs available. Can you post an example of which style you are trying to reproduce, and what you have seen so far? Are you making hinges as separate components, or do you want them to be integral to your project? Asking for plans is out-of-scope for the main SE site, but you can still inquire about specific techniques if you have some illustrations to help convey what you are thinking.

Comment: Successful wooden hinge projects that I have seen, incorporate the hinge into the design such that if you were making something like a lidded box, one part of the hinge would be part of the lid (not simply attached) and the other half of the hinge would be part of a face of the box.

Comment: Websearch should find several designs, plus jigs to make creating wooden hinges easier...

Comment: It sounds like the same approaches as are used to cut dovetails would apply.

Comment: Research "box joints", a.k.a. finger joints. I'm not entirely clear of your intent but that may help. I did my first ones this last year, they are easy once you setup. The require a router table and would work for hinges. You might also consider using laminated versus solid blanks.